Storage problems with JPA
There are tables with two-way associations.
public class AuthorityEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO,generator="native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native",strategy = "native")
    @Column(name="authority_id")
    private Long id;
    
    private String role;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private UserEntity user;
    

}
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private Long id;
    
    private String email;
    
    private String pwd;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<AuthorityEntity> authorities;
    
    
}

public String joinService(UserEntity userInfo) {
        try {
            Set<AuthorityEntity> setAuthority = new HashSet<>();
            setAuthority.add(AuthorityEntity.builder().role("AICALL").build());
            UserEntity user = UserEntity.builder()
                    .email(userInfo.getEmail())
                    .pwd(passwordEncoder.encode(userInfo.getPwd()))
                    .authorities(setAuthority)
                    .build();
            userRepository.save(user);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return "ok";
    }

You want to store data in the table that you refer to.
However, if you save the data, the user_id column in the authority table is entered with a null value.
Why is that?

The user_id column in the AuthorityEntity table is being saved null, is due to the fact that the relationship between UserEntity and AuthorityEntity is not being fully established in both directions.
In the joinService method, you are creating a UserEntity and associating AuthorityEntity instances with it by setting the authorities field, but you also need to set the user field to point back to the UserEntity for each AuthorityEntity.
You can change your code to something like this:
  UserEntity user = UserEntity.builder()
                .email(userInfo.getEmail())
                .pwd(passwordEncoder.encode(userInfo.getPwd()))
                .build();

        authority.setUser(user);

        if (user.getAuthorities() == null) {
            user.setAuthorities(new HashSet<>());
        }

        user.getAuthorities().add(authority);
userRepository.save(user);

